# Fedora 23 how to install driver for BCM43142 802.11?

Tags: fedora, wifi

I recently switched to Linux from Mac, and I am having a hard time getting the wireless to work on Fedora 23. I read many threads regarding this problem but none of them worked for me. I tried things like `yum install kmod-wl` returns a message `no package akmod-kl available`, and I tried manually installing package from the folllowing link:
https://www.rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/search.php?query=broadcom-wl 
for whatever reason, whenever I tried to install one of listed packages. The system returns a message of

> the installation of common files for broadcom 802.11 STA driver failed.

Comment: You have to install the firmware files/packages first. I am more used to Debian, someone more experienced with Fedora will certainly help you.

Answer (score 2):

I had this issue around an year back (with Feodra 21) and ended up writing a blog post about it: http://www.gautham.net/2015/01/broadcom-wl-driver-working-fedora-21-akmod-wl-bcm4312.html

In a nutshell though you seem to have not enabled the RPM Fusion repositories, which are required for the akmods package and the akmod-wl package. See http://rpmfusion.org/ for more information.

Comment: Excellent URL. I am however obliged to tell you people seem to value more elaborate posts, and there is a policy of encouraging people to paste relevant parts of external links to the answer itself. With time, you will notice it too.

Comment: Point noted. In this situation, since the OP did not mention enabling RPM Fusion, I assumed that it was the reason why (a)kmod-wl wasn't able to be installed. If I had written instructions to enable RPM Fusion, that might have quickly been outdated but its website would forever have the latest how-to.

Comment: @mahtuag, hi, I followed your instructions(sort of) and installed RPM fusion(both free and non-free). After that, `sudo yum install kernel-devel akmod-wl` and `sudo systemctl restart NetworkManager` on the terminal, but the wireless is still not working..

Comment: Did you do `sudo akmods` ? That should build your driver. If the output indicates no errors, you should restart NetworkManager again and see if WiFi is enabled now.

Comment: I tried that. and it gives the same output Parag Bansal, who commented on your blog, was having.

Comment: Can you check whether current kernel has the corresponding kernel-devel installed ? The versions should match. One way to achieve this is just update your system `sudo dnf update --refresh`, restart, select newest kernel in boot menu and see if the wireless works now. This should usually install the latest kernel and kernel-devel so the versions would match.

Comment: I did all that and I booted from fedora 4.2.8-300 86x64, but the wireless option is not available :-(

Comment: `sudo akmods` returns `Checking kmods exist for 4.2.8-300.fc23.x86_64             [  OK  ]
`

Comment: You should use the `modprobe` command (learn syntax here https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Kernel_modules) to see if the wl module is currently loaded successfully.

PS: Beyond this you may need someone else's help.

I believe you are trying to get wireless working on Fedora installed on a MacBook. I tried the same on an eMachines laptop with a slightly different wireless chip. Under the circumstances, you'll probably have an easier time copying the setup of someone with a working Fedora installation on the MacBook model you own. Suggest asking in #fedora on freenode (IRC) for this.